# Wrong colors in Toggle button widget icons

Tags: flutter, colors, material-design, themes

I have a toggle button widget added to the appbar in the actions section. This is how it looks:

[image]

As you see icon colors are not correct. The selected one color is the same color as the appbar and the other icons show black. Oddly, the other icon added to the appbar outside the Toggle button widget is white:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() async {

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Project',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
            // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
              title: Text("Game Manager"),
              actions: [
                Row(children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: ToggleButtons(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                        /*borderColor: Colors.blue,
                        selectedBorderColor: Colors.blue[200],
                        selectedColor: Colors.white,
                        fillColor: Colors.blue[300],
                        color: Colors.blue[300],*/
                        onPressed: (int i) => print("pressed!"),
                        isSelected: const [true,false,false],
                        children: [
                          Tooltip(message: "sort_by_name", child: const Icon(Icons.receipt)),
                          Tooltip(message: "sort_by_status", child: const Icon(Icons.stars)),
                          Tooltip(message: "sort_by_size", child: const Icon(Icons.storage))
                        ]),
                  ),

                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("Yeah");
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.unfold_less),
                    tooltip: "fold_all",
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    tooltip: "refresh",
                  ),
                ]
                )
              ]),
          body: Container()

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PubSpec.yaml:

```
name: project
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
  - assets/images/logo.png
  - assets/translations/
```

Comment: Are you overriding theme property on top level? also it would be easier if you provide sample widget that will reproduce the error.

Comment: I added a reproducible example. Hope it is enough.

Comment: @Notbad, if you uncomment selectedColor: Colors.white, it solve your problem as of now .

Comment: I know that wiould fixed it. But this was a patch I did to see if it worked. The thing is, I want to make it work without workarounds. Why is it showing these colors when using the default light() theme? That's the question. On the other hand if I uncomment the selectedColor I have to do a bit more work because I use 2 differnt themes. Can't this be achieved at Theme level? Moreover, shouldn't this work out of the box?

Comment: Uncommenting your color solves it ?

Comment: Nope, this is why I created the question. Have been checking the sources but did not find anything special.